# Prove that $\sigma_a(x) = x^a$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_n = \langle x \rangle$ if and only if $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

My proof:  Suppose that $\sigma_a$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_n$.
Then $\sigma_a$ should preserve the order of the elements in
$\mathbb{Z}_n.$ Now let $x^j \in \mathbb{Z}_n$.
$|x^j| = \frac{n}{\text{gcd}(j, n)} = |\sigma_a(x^j)| = |x^{aj}| =
            \frac{n}{\text{gcd}(aj, n)} =
            \frac{n}{\text{gcd}(a,n)\text{gcd}(j, n)}$, which implies
$\text{gcd}(a, n) = 1$. \ Now suppose that $a$ and $n$ are
relatively prime. Let $x^m, x^n \in \mathbb{Z}_n$. Suppose
that $x^m = x^n$. Then $\sigma_a(x^m) = x^{ma} = x^{na} = \sigma(x^n)$,
so $\sigma_a$ is well defined. Since $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is cyclic,
it is abelian, so $\sigma_a(x^mx^n) = (x^mx^n)^a =
            x^{ma}x^{na} = \sigma_a(x^m)\sigma_a(x^n)$, meaning $\sigma_a$
is a homomorphism. Let $x^{pa} \in \mathbb{Z}_n$. Since
$\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a group, $x^{pa}x^{-a} = x^p \in
            \mathbb{Z}_n$, so $\sigma_a$ is surjective. Since
$|\mathbb{Z}_n| = |\mathbb{Z}_n|$, this means that $\sigma_a$
is an isomorphism.

Is there any step or fundamental information that I'm missing here?

Comment: Since $\Bbb{Z}_n$ is an additive group, the map $x\mapsto  x^a$ is an automorphism only if $a=1$.

Comment: @MarkSapir I meant to add that the question thinks of $Z_n = \langle x \rangle$.

Comment: Now the three $x$'s in the title have different meanings.

Comment: The equation $ \frac{n}{gcd(aj,n)} = \frac{n}{gcd(a,n)gcd(j,n)} $ is not justified, and in fact I think it assumes exactly what you're trying to prove.

Comment: Your proof should make reference to the fact that $ a $ and $ n $ are relatively prime if and only if the diophantine equation $ ax + ny = 1 $ has a solution $ x,y\in\mathbb{Z} $.

Comment: @MarkSapir yeah that's how the question was stated exactly though

Comment: @JakeMirra i forgot that that's only if $\gcd(a, b) = 1$. How about this:  $|x^j| = \frac{n}{\text{gcd}(j, n)} = |\sigma_a(x^j)| = |x^{aj}| =
            \frac{n}{\text{gcd}(aj, n)} = \frac{n}{\gcd(n, aj \mod n)}$, which implies
                $a \equiv 1 \mod n$, meaning $n$ and $a$ are coprime.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the OP asks that we prove $\gcd(a,n)=1$ iff $\varphi:\bar{x}\mapsto\bar{a}\bar{x}$ is a $\Bbb Z_n^+$ group automorphism where $\bar{x}$ is the residue class $x+n\Bbb Z$. Recall $\gcd(a,n)=1$ iff $\text{lcm}(a,n)=an$ and note $\varphi$ is $\Bbb Z_n^+$ endomorphism as $$\varphi(\bar{x}+\bar{y})=\bar{a}(\bar{x}+\bar{y})=\bar{a}\bar{x}+\bar{a}\bar{y}=\varphi(\bar{x})+\varphi(\bar{y})$$ $$\therefore\;\text{lcm}(a,n)=an\iff\bar{a},\overline{2a},\dots,\overline{(n-1)a}\neq\bar{0}\iff\ker(\varphi)=\{\bar{0}\}\iff\varphi\in\text{Aut}(\Bbb Z_n^+)$$